# What could cause Laravel to read from another project's ENV file?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-10, php-8.1

I am using XAMPP with 3 projects in the `htdocs` folder.

suddenly one of the Laravel projects started reading the `.env` values of another project.

After I restarted XAMPP it was fixed.

Each project is using its own local domain in the `hosts` file

Comment: I encountered a similar problem when I used an outdated environment file that had been cached. Even after I modified the environment variables, the cached file was still being used. It's possible that your situation is also related to caching.